# Taking Json object as input parameter in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am trying to use the Jenkins pipeline for Json format input. I am trying to pass the Json format String in multiline string parameter where I am passing parameter like below image but I am not able to able to parse it using JsonSlurper, where test is the name of the multiline string input. Can anyone help me how can I parse it in groovy?

Is it possible to parse the Json format in multiline string parameter ?

[multiline string parameter input as Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gacO.png)

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def infra = jsonSlurper.parse($test) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use JsonSulper for this, you can use [readJson](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) step instead. Here is a complete sample.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters { string(name: 'JSON', defaultValue: 'staging', description: '') }
  stages {
      stage ("Example") {
        steps {
         script{
            def jsonObj = readJSON text: "${params.JSON}"
            echo "$jsonObj"
        } }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also tell how to access values from jsonObj?

Comment: @AnujSharma This depends on the structure of your JSON. There are bunch of examples here https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace